# Print HTML in Scala template

Tags: playframework-2.0, scala-template

I need to print some raw HTML in Scala template using newest **Play Framework 2.1.1** Messages, variables, simple for loops etc. everything is working fine. But what if I need to to do some logic and print out raw HTML into template?

```
@{
    val courts = venue.getCourts()
    val totalWidth : Int = 920
    .. some other initialization variables/values

    var output : String = ""
    for(court <- courts) {
        output += "<p>SomeComplexString</p>"
    }

    output
}
```

In this case `@{}` function returns `output` but that HTML is escaped and also it's not so practical (combining everything into single `output` variable before returning).

If I put something like

```
for(court <- courts) {
    println("<p>SomeComplexString</p>")
}
```

it's not working (I don't get any compile errors but there is nothing on output).

I could do

```
@for(court <- courts) {
    <p>SomeComplexString</p>
}
```

but then `courts` would be out-of-scope (let just say I can't define `courts` as template variable on the beginning).

What is the solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> But what if I need to to do some logic and print out raw HTML into template?

Play Framework, like others MVC frameworks, recommends a strict separation of concerns. Your logic must be in your controller, not in the view. It's why it's relatively complicated to do that in the scala templates.

Furthermore, you can use [@Html()](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaTemplates) to display unescaped variables.

Comment: correct answer but avoid using `@Html()` because of security concerns.

Comment: @adis Can you please specify the security concerns of @Html()?

Comment: @user1943442 script injection if you just use `@Html` out of a user input. Read some more: http://wonko.com/post/html-escaping

Comment: @adis Ah I thought there was something I was missing.   I think avoiding the use of @Html() is bad advice. It's a necessary function.  The better advice would be be aware of it's implications when applied to user-input.

Comment: @user1943442 Totally agree with your arguments!